# SciPy: solve_bvp Problem 2nd Order Diff. Eq

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

Trying to solve a 2nd order diff. eq. with 2 boundary conditions and nothing I try seems to work and I can't find a tutorial which includes all/similar terms to what I have in my expression and, at least to me, the scipy documentation doesn't really explain how to use solve_bvp clearly.

I have the equation: y'' + 2/r * y' = A * y + b * y^3 where y is a function of r.

I've rewritten it as follows:

y1 = y(r)

y2 = y1'

so that y2' = -2/r * y2 + y1(A + b * y1^2)

With conditions that y'(0) = 0, y(r=10) = constant

A, b and the constant are known.

I have the following code but it doesn't seem to work, and as said, I'm a little confused by the documentation so any help would be appreciated!

```
def fun(x, y):
    return np.vstack((y[2], -2/x*y[1]+y[0]*(A+b*y[0]*y[0])))

def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[2], yb[1]-constant])


x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
ya = np.zeros((3, x.size))
yb = np.zeros((3, x.size))

sol_1 = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, ya)
sol_2 = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, yb)
```

Thanks!

==========EDIT=========================
There is an analytical solution, for which I have calculated, it was just seeing if I could also find the same solution numerically, I think the major issue is that there are two separate regions for the solutions, one where r < R (in) and one where r > R (out). This leads to two different solutions (only valid in their respective domain) with the conditions that y_in(R) == y_out(R) and y_in'(R) == y_out'(R). [Full 2-part solution where Radius = 1, a=99, b = 1 and constant = 1, y(inf) = constant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UljzK.png)

From Lutz Lehmann's solution, it gets the right shape (at least for the inner region, although not on the right scales).

I'm just unsure how you'd go about coding all the equating solutions and I suppose even getting their solutions in the first place, although Lutz's answer is an amazing point in the right direction.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues

- The order of the equation is 2, thus the dimension of the state vector is 2, the value is always `y[0]`, the derivative `y[1]`, there is no `y[2]`, probably a remnant from the translation from Matlab.
- Also in the boundary conditions, there is no `ya[2]`, the derivative value is `ya[1]`, and the function value in the second one is `yb[0]`.
- The initial solution guess has to have the same number 2 of state components.
- Why do you compute two solutions with identical data?
- Remark: It is not necessary to convert the return values into numpy types, the solver checks and converts anyway.

### BVP framework with singularity treatment

The ODE is singular at `r=0`, so one has to treat the first segment in a special way. The mean value theorem gives

```
(y'(r)-y'(0))/r->y''(0)  for  r->0,
```

so that in that limit `r->0` you get

```
3*y''(0) = a*y(0) + b*y(0)^3`.
```

This allows to define the first arc as

```
y(r) = y0 + (a*y0 + b*y0^3)*r^2/6
y'(r) = (a*y0 + b*y0^3)*r/3
```

up to order `r³` and `r²`. So if you want precision `1e-9` in `y(r)`, then the first segment should not be longer than `1e-3`.

Instead of trying to eliminate `y0` from the equations for `y(h)` and `y'(h)` to get a condition connecting `ya[0]` and `ya[1]`, let the solver do also this work and add `y0` as parameter to the system. Then the boundary conditions have 3 slots corresponding to the added virtual dimension for the parameter, which can be naturally filled with the equations `y(h)=ya[0]` and `ya[1]=y'(h)` and the right boundary condition.

Altogether you can define the system as

```py
h = 1e-3;

def fun(r, y, p):
    return  y[1], -2/r*y[1]+y[0]*(a+b*y[0]*y[0]) 

def bc(ya, yb, p):
    y0, = p
    yh = y0 + y0*(a+b*y0*y0)*h*h/6;
    dyh = y0*(a+b*y0*y0)*h/3
    return ya[0]-yh, ya[1]-dyh, yb[0]-c


x = np.linspace(h, 10, 10)
ya = np.zeros((2, x.size))

sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, ya, p=[1])
print(sol.message,f"y(0)={sol.p[0]}");
plt.plot(sol.x, sol.y[0]);
```

so that with example parameters `a, b, c = -1, 0.2, 3` you get a convergent solver call with `y(0)=2.236081087849196` and the resulting plot

[image]

Comment: This is the perfect answer, thank you so much! I think its mainly just which element represents what for the boundary conditions, but your explanation with the singularity is great!

Comment: How would I alter it such that instead of y(r=10) = const, it was y(r-->inf) --> const?

Comment: That would only be possible if `c=0` or `c^2=-a/b`, if the right side is positive. Else you do not get a constant at infinity, but the behavior of the friction-less system, periodic oscillations or divergence to infinity. And even then not all variants are possible, only those that are stable equilibrium points