# How to implement neumann and reflecting boundary condition into bvp5/4c function?

Tags: numerical-methods

I came across this [second order non linear ODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsmSy.png)

How do i input the BCs into bvp5/4c function and is this possible to be solved by bvp5/4c function?

Comment: Your equation is singular at `x=0`, you need to solve this singularity manually by a power series expansion. Then with that make a new boundary at `x=h>0`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293084/scipy-solve-bvp-problem-2nd-order-diff-eq/60319225#60319225 for a similar problem with a solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422538/how-to-solve-an-algebraic-equation-in-formal-power-series on how to semi-manually compute the coefficients of a power series solution. To apply this almost literally you need to multiply your DE with `x^2`, that is, use `x^2*a''+2*x*a'-x^2*a*(C_1*a+C_2)=0`, so that the new coefficient equation for coefficient `a_k` appears in the power `x^k`.

Comment: It would also help if you could give your equation as text, using `a''(x)` is completely acceptable for a text-style formula. Also give some values for the parameters, either the ones given for the task, one ones typical for the intended range of parameters.